# Fatal Error: Call to a member function getProductUrl()

Tags: magento-1.9, error, fatal-error

When I am trying to use the code

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku2)->getProductUrl();
```

in my cart page i am getting the error as

```
Fatal Error: Call to a member function getProductUrl() in boolean
```

Can anyone kindly tell me why am I getting this.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error, because `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku2)` just returns `false`. Please check your SKU *(`$sku2`)* ... if this is invalid, you'll see this error.

I'd recommend adding a check if product exists ...

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku2);
if ($product->getId()) {
    echo $product->getProductUrl();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help I got the answer by changing the code that I have mentioned in the answer that I have written below

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using the following line of code instead of the code that I have mentioned in the question above.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sku2)->getProductUrl();
```

Comment: This does not match your question ... either looking for ID or SKU ;)

Comment: I was getting that error when I was trying to get the URL :)

Comment: Yes, because invalid SKU in `loadByAttribute` ;) Change your code to the original one and use a valid SKU and it will work too :)